# Material-UI - Why should I use makeStyles instead of inline styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com), there is the `makeStyles` function which can be used to get custom CSS-Styling.

Should I use it if I am not using a theme in that specific CSS?

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField, Paper, Button, Box } from "@material-ui/core";

const classes = {
  paper: {
      backgroundColor: "#eee",
      marginLeft: "30%",
       marginRight: "30%"
  },
  textField: {
      backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  button: {
      backgroundColor: "green",
      marginLeft: 20
  }
};

const Ohne = () => {
  console.log(classes);
  return (
      <Paper style={classes.paper}>
      <Box>
          <TextField style={classes.textField} />
          <Button style={classes.button}>abc</Button>
      </Box>
      </Paper>
  );
};

export default Ohne;
```

The object was:

```
{
    "paper": {
        "backgroundColor": "#eee",
        "marginLeft": "30%",
        "marginRight": "30%"
    },
    "textField": {
        "backgroundColor": "#fff"
    },
    "button": {
        "backgroundColor": "green",
        "marginLeft": 20
    }
}
```

**vs**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { TextField, Paper, Button, Box } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
      backgroundColor: "#eee",
      marginLeft: "30%",
      marginRight: "30%"
  },
  textField: {
      backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  button: {
      backgroundColor: "green",
      marginLeft: 20
  }
}));

const Mit = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  console.log(classes);
  return (
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <Box>
          <TextField className={classes.textField} />
          <Button className={classes.button}>abc</Button>
      </Box>
      </Paper>
  );
};

export default Mit;
```

The object was:

```
{
    "paper": "makeStyles-paper-85",
    "textField": "makeStyles-textField-86",
    "button": "makeStyles-button-87"
}
```

So there are 3 main points (that I see):

1. One way creates classes and references them, the other just uses the object as is.
2. In the first case an object is assigned to the `style` property which is inline and has a higher priority.
3. In the first example it is important to keep the `const` outside of the class, so the object is still created only once and won't trigger a rerender.

But the resulting component looks identical (in my Firefox).

My questions:

- Can an example be constructed where these two approaches result in different controls?
- Is there any performance aspect to it?
- Any other differences?

Comment: It would help to see how you are using `classes`. I don't see how the resulting controls could look the same in the two cases unless it isn't having any effect in either case (i.e. looks the same if you don't have anything in `classes`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few scenarios where using CSS classes (e.g. via [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#hook-api) or [`withStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api)) is necessary:

- If you want to use [media queries](https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/#css-media-queries) in your CSS
- If you want to target pseudo-classes (e.g. [:hover](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.0/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L21))
- If you are creating a reusable customization of one of the Material-UI components and want to customize some of the classes that are conditionally applied to the element based on props or some other context (e.g. if you want to customize the "error" look of an [Input](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#css) while leaving it up to the places where the custom component is used to specify the `error` prop either directly or via the `FormControl` context)

As far as performance concerns, I would expect inline styles to be faster for most use cases. Whether the difference is enough to matter would depend on a lot of specifics regarding your particular application. The team I work with uses `makeStyles` or `withStyles` for most of our styling.

Inline styles can result in a lot of duplicated CSS in the DOM if a particular component is rendered many times within the document (e.g. list items, table cells, etc.). One nice thing about always using classes is that you can change the CSS for the class in the browser's developer tools and see that change applied throughout all its usages in the document.

Comment: So after using it and playing around with both options for a few months, I found your last sentance to be the most useful/have the biggest impact to day-to-day work. Having a class assigned to all relevant elements, and testing a change in the dev-tools, just saves development time (avoiding rebuilds, and re-navigating to that page where the change is made). Thanks!

Comment: What about keeping a separate file instead of inline css?